# Advice on encoding data in UTF8 vs. standard Latin in rails app with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I'm developing a Rails app and all has been going well until today when I tried to do some ETL on the data I had made changes to through the app.  I was comparing 2 columns.  One was standard and the other was UTF8.  I'm sure I can get around this by decoding one of the columns for the comparison, but I have a larger question.  Is what happened normal with a Rails app?  Is it advisable to just use UTF8 encoding in my entire DB from the outset?  database.yml is set to use UTF8 encoding, should I just set it to Latin?  We're not going to be using any extraordinary symbols now, but we are an international company and perhaps the app could spread.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: You should always use UTF8.

Comment: SLacks, you would suggest that I convert my entire db to UTF8 before any operations with Rails?  I think that's the easiest and best solution.  Do others agree?

Comment: Are you just looking for a consensus (3 upvotes thus far with no alternative posted)?  Or do you have a reason not to use UTF-8?

Comment: http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ although this assumes an unicode encoding, which is a no-brainer. It's more of a UTF-16 vs UTF-8.